# no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘hockey::Personne* const’ and ‘const hockey::Personne’)

Tags: c++

my function tries to find if an element already exists in a vector of a class objects pointers
I kind of understand the source of the problem but I can't seem to find a solution without having the implement a method for the == operation ,

the method in the cpp file :

```
bool Annuaire::PersonneEstDejaPresente(const Personne& p_personne) const{
     vector<Personne*>::const_iterator iter;
     iter = std::find(m_vMembres.begin(), m_vMembres.end(), p_personne);
     return true;         
                                                 //the return here is just for the sake of testing
}
```

the vector defined in the header file private part :

```
std::vector<Personne*> m_vMembres;
```

the error I get from the compiler is in the title,

I would be really apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that have an vector of pointers but what you are looking for is not a pointer.

This would compile

```
iter = std::find(m_vMembres.begin(), m_vMembres.end(), &p_personne);
```

but this will compare pointers not `Personne` objects. I guess that you really want to compare persons, so you might be better off using `std::find_if` instead of `std::find`.

The other thing you should consider is using `vector<Personne>` instead of `vector<Personne*>`. Do you have a good reason to use pointers in the first place?

Comment: thanks a lot that solved it , and yes I need pointers because the Personne objects are objects from multiple classes derived from  Personne class so the only solution to compare them as far as I know  is to use pointers